# Style of this sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, syntactic-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for inverting word order to accomplish a different meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/is-there-a-name-for-inverting-word-order-to-accomplish-a-different-meaning)

I came across this sentence recently and I was wondering what is this repetitive style called? Also, can anyone provide me with another few interesting examples of sentences like this?

> I wish people would say what they mean and mean what they say.