# What rhetorical device is used in the sentence?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

What rhetorical device is used in the sentence "They are unconventionally rich and richly unconventional"?

Comment: How about [polyptoton](https://www.thoughtco.com/polyptoton-rhetoric-1691641)?

Comment: [Chiasmus](https://www.thoughtco.com/chiasmus-figure-of-speech-1689838) seems to suit better.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a term to cover this. Note that 'rich' and 'richly' are not merely intercategorial variants, they have different subsenses here too. Not quite as bad as Popeye's "You're awful preddy!" ... Olive Oyle: "You're pretty awful yourself!" _But covered here before._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a name for inverting word order to accomplish a different meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/is-there-a-name-for-inverting-word-order-to-accomplish-a-different-meaning)