# Name of literary device and examples

Tags: literary-techniques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for inverting word order to accomplish a different meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/is-there-a-name-for-inverting-word-order-to-accomplish-a-different-meaning)
>   [“Some champagne for my real friends, some real pain for my sham friends.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22219/some-champagne-for-my-real-friends-some-real-pain-for-my-sham-friends)
>   [Style of this sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/style-of-this-sentence)

I recall once knowing a name for a statement like "I love to hate and hate to love." What is the name? I am also interested in other examples of this from popular poetry, music lyrics, etc.